# Javascript/Node/Express: res.json needs to wait for a function to finish running before returning... but res.json is impatient?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Hello friends! I hope you are well.

So in this snippet of code, I have a list of ten servers I want to query. These ten servers are represented by the ten ports I have defined up top in the const "ports".

The idea is to use forEach() on "ports", and run the query on each server. An object is returned by each run of the query and added into the initially empty array "data".

THEN! After "data" has been loaded with the ten objects containing the status of my servers, I want it dished back to the client side!

However..... this is not what happens. Port.forEach() runs the query just fine, and adds into the array "data"... but not before res.json jumps the gun and sends off an empty data back to my soon to be disappointed client.

So far... I've tried callbacks and async/await... but I haven't figured out the syntax for it.. Any tips would be awesome! Thank you for your time friendos!

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.get("/api/seMapServerStatus", (req, res) => {

  const ports = [ "27111", "27112", "27117", "27118", "27119", "27110", "27115", "27116", "27113", "27114" ]
  const data = []

    function hitServers(port){
        Gamedig.query({
          type: "aGameType",
          host: "theServer'sIP",
          port: port
        }).then((state) => {
          data.push(state)
          console.log("this is the server", state)
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log("Server is offline");
        });  
    };

    ports.forEach(port => {
      hitServers(port)
    })
  });
  console.log("and here is the final server list", data)
  res.json(data);   
}
```

Comment: `res.json()` isn't impatient, your `forEach()` is.

Comment: Because the AJAX calls to the servers are async, data isn't filled before it's returned (unless the stars align, maybe.) Change your export to something like `(app, callback) => { ...`  where callback is a function that takes data as a paramater. In your then block, you can do `callback(data)` Or `callback(res.json(data))`, whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code executes synchronously, therefore you return in the same frame before any promise has the chance to resolve.

We can clean the above code up as follows:

```js
module.exports = app => {

  app.get("/api/seMapServerStatus", (req, res) => {
    const ports = ["27111", "27112", "27117", "27118", "27119", "27110", "27115", "27116", "27113", "27114"]

    function hitServers(port) {
      return Gamedig.query({
        type: "aGameType",
        host: "theServer'sIP",
        port: port
      })
    }

    // With error handling
    function hitServersSafe(port) {
      return hitServers(port)
        .then(result => {
          return {
            success: true,
            result: result
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          return {
            success: false,
             // you probably need to serialize error
            error: error
          }
        })
    }

    const promises = ports.map(port => hitServers(port))
    // With error handling
    // const promises = ports.map(port => hitServersSafe(port))

    Promise
      .all(promises)
      .then(data => res.json(data))
      .catch(error => {
        // do something with error
      })
  })

}
```

We map each port to a promise. After we have a list of X promises we wait for [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) of them to finish.

The calling `Promise.all()` returns an array of resolved values, or rejects when any promise rejects.

Only after all of the promises have resolved we can move on and send the result to the client.

Comment: Mm. Running this straight up returns with the 'error catching' script. 

Attempting to log the data at any level comes back with "pending" or as of yet undefined...

Comment: No wait!! There problem was that one of the servers was down. This code works wonderfully! Thank you!!

Comment: Great! Don't forget to return a response (for example 500) if an error occurs because otherwise the client will be left hanging.

Comment: Riiiiight. I'm reading now about error handling with promise.all. Ideally. I'd like the good results to be passed along with the errors for handoff to the client.

Comment: In such case Promise.all would fail if any one query fails. I updated my answer to add a safe version which catches the error and transforms it before passing the promises to `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Hey I appreciate that! You're the best! 

I also see that with the absolute latest version of Node, there's the Promise.allSettled() method!

Comment: Now that they are pure functions, you might also consider hoisting the `hitServers*` functions up out of the handler to prevent their redefinition on each request.

Also, there's not really any reason to do `ports.map(port => hitServers(port))` rather than just `ports.map(hitServers)`